# CSV manipulation with python 3

Tags: python, csv

I've created a script in python 3 to scrape data from 4 different pages of a site. It works fine but when i try to get that result in a csv file, something goes wrong and it only prints the info of the last page. Could anybody help me out on this. i've attached the script for your consideration. Dying to know what i'm doing wrong.

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def web_crawler(mpage):
    page=1
    while page<=mpage:
        url=requests.get("http://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=Coffee%20Shops&geo_location_terms=San%20Francisco%2C%20CA&page="+str(page))
        soup=BeautifulSoup(url.text,'html.parser')
        x=soup.findAll(class_='info')
        gist=[]
        for z in x:
            Item=z.findAll(class_="business-name")
            for Title in Item:
                Name=Title.text
                Patta=z.findAll(class_="adr")
            for Thikana in Patta:
                Address=Thikana.text
                Number=z.findAll(class_="phones")
            for Token in Number:
                Phone=Token.text
                metco=(Name,Address,Phone)
                print(metco)
                gist.append(metco)

            outfile=open('data.csv','w',newline='')
            writer=csv.writer(outfile)
            writer.writerow(["Name","Address","Phone"])
            writer.writerows(gist)                 

        page+=1                        
web_crawler(4)
```

Comment: open a file with w erases maybe existing files. Please read docu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overwriting your file in the loop

```
outfile=open('data.csv','w',newline='')
```

try moving it out of the main loop.

Comment: Tried, but found the same result as i am now. If i am not making mistake you are suggesting something like this:    
page+=1
outfile=open('data.csv','w',newline=' ')                  writer=csv.writer(outfile)
writer.writerow(["Name","Address","Phone"])
writer.writerows(gist)

Comment: Just do `outfile=open('data.csv', 'w')` before `while page <= mpage:`

Comment: Thanks a lot sir "Maximilian Peters". It works what you just suggested. It is now working fine. I didn't get you first. But the code looks a bit awkward as i have put that line, you mentioned, on the very top where the code begins. Any suggestion on that, please. The code is working fine, though.